# Null pointer Exception while using ternary operator in Talen Studio

Tags: etl, talend

I am using talend for some ETL operations, I was trying to use ternary operator for some logical work but getting `nullpointer` exception from talend.

**What I want to do** - I am having source database which is having one column in table named "time_zone" its of integer type, containing Enum like- 1,2,3,4.....12 in destination table I want to replace these with some String like is the value is 0 I want to write "EST_GMT_0" in my destination table.

**What I tried** - Earlier I tried one approach that worked but now I found some issues on that approach -

```
String.valueOf(row12.time_zone).replace("0","AST_GMT_4").replace("1","EST_GMT_5").replace("2","CST_GMT_6").replace("3","MST_GMT_7").replace("4","PST_GMT_8").replace("5","AST_GMT_9").replace("6","HST_GMT_10").replace("7","ADT_GMT_3").replace("8","EDT_GMT_4").replace("9","CDT_GMT_5").replace("10","ADT_GMT_6").replace("11","ADT_GMT_7").replace("12","ADT_GMT_8")
```

Earlier I was doing it like this but the issue here is the output will be not as expected It also replaces the last replaced String, because replaced string containing number like `EDT_GMT_4` replace method again replaces 4 with some other String value and soo on until it wont react higher values, as in the result the final output becomes - `MST_GMT_ADT_GMT_MST_GMT_7` like this

**Other Approach I tried** -

```
String.valueOf(row12.time_zone).equals("0")?String.valueOf(row12.time_zone).replace("0","ZERO"):String.valueOf(row12.time_zone).equals("1")?String.valueOf(row12.time_zone).replace("1","One"):String.valueOf(row12.time_zone).equals("2")?String.valueOf(row12.time_zone).replace("2","Two"):String.valueOf(row12.time_zone).equals("3")?String.valueOf(row12.time_zone).replace("3","Three"):String.valueOf(row12.time_zone).equals("4")?String.valueOf(row12.time_zone).replace("4","Four"):String.valueOf(row12.time_zone).equals("5")?String.valueOf(row12.time_zone).replace("5","Five"):String.valueOf(row12.time_zone).equals("6")?String.valueOf(row12.time_zone).replace("6","Six"):String.valueOf(row12.time_zone).equals("7")?String.valueOf(row12.time_zone).replace("7","Seven"):String.valueOf(row12.time_zone).equals("8")?String.valueOf(row12.time_zone).replace("8","Eight"):String.valueOf(row12.time_zone).equals("9")?String.valueOf(row12.time_zone).replace("9","Nine"):row12.time_zone.equals("10")?String.valueOf(row12.time_zone).replace("10","Ten"):String.valueOf(row12.time_zone).equals("11")?String.valueOf(row12.time_zone).replace("11","Eleven"):String.valueOf(row12.time_zone).equals("12")?String.valueOf(row12.time_zone).replace("12","Twelve"):String.valueOf(row12.time_zone)
```

That was the second approach I tried but got `NullPointerException`

How to resolve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your other approach, for the value ten (10) replacement, you forgot to apply the same java method ***String.valueOf()*** to convert integer to String before you can go through comparison tests. Some of your input rows (integer type) are null, and you cannot apply directly string ***equals*** method to those rows.

So, that part of your ternary operation

```
:row12.time_zone.equals("10")?String.valueOf(row12.time_zone).replace("10","Ten")
```

should be this (like the other lines)

```
:String.valueOf(row12.time_zone).equals("10")?String.valueOf(row12.time_zone).replace("10","Ten")
```

Comment: Yes thanks for pointing out this issue.